# Under what conditions would photons interact to create pair production?

Tags: photons, pair-production

I understand that two photons colliding can result in pair production but under what conditions would this happen? Would the photons have to be in a superconductive state or is it just by chance, as this is not something that occurs regularly on Earth (at least I think that is the case)?

Comment: What would it mean for *photons* to be "in a superconductive state"?

Comment: @ACuriousMind it would mean that there would be a state of zero electrical resistance

Comment: Um, I know what superconduction is. But photon states do not have an obvious notion of resistance, so what are you talking about when you say that a photon state is "superconductive"?

Comment: I mean the area around it...no interference from any other objects or particles in the surrounding environment that may affect how the photons interact with eachother

Answer (score 2):

The main condition is that the sum of the energies of the photons would be higher than two times the mass of the element whose pair your are trying to create, this can be seen by energy conservation:

$$ E_{\gamma_1} + E_{\gamma_2} = K_1 + K_2 + 2 m c^2  $$

Where $E$ is the energy of each photon before collision, $K$ is the kinetik energy of each particle and $m$ the mass of both particles, since $K_1 + K_2 \geq 0$ we need that $ E_{\gamma_1} + E_{\gamma_2} \geq 2mc^2 $.

Of course depending on the pair you want to create there might be other conditions related to quantum spin, but if this condition is not fulfilled the pair would not be generated.

Notice also that pairs can be created spontaneously by one photon only, if it fulfills the inequality above, these are called virtual pairs since they usually recombinate to produce a photon again in a very short timescale.

Comment: Since most elements created in pair production are extremely small, I would think most combinations - or even single - photons would fulfill that inequality. Is this a common occurrence, and if not, why?

Comment: Not really, for instance to create an electron and a positron you need a photon with an energy of $\sim 1 MeV$ you need a photon with a frequency (roughly) of $\sim 2.5 \cdot 10^{20} Hz$, these are gamma rays, generated in some nuclear decays and in high energy experiments.